# Having trouble displaying a notepads averages

Tags: python

I need to make a program that displays an average of about 5 numbers from a notepad file. I feel that I have most of the code right but I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer."

How can I fix it? Here's my code:

```
def main():
    numbers = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

    list_numbers = numbers.readline()

    amount = float(list_numbers)

    for value in range(amount): # <----- ERROR HAPPENS ON THIS LINE
        amount += value

    average = total / len(numbers)
    print('The average of numbers is', average)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `range` built-in only accepts integer arguments:

```
>>> range(10.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>> range(10)
range(0, 10)
>>>
```

Thus, `amount` needs to be an integer:

```
amount = int(list_numbers)
```

Also, you forgot to close the file at the end of your function. You can use a [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) so that this is done automatically:

```
def main():
    with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as numbers:
        list_numbers = numbers.readline()

        amount = int(list_numbers)

        for value in range(amount):
            amount += value

        average = total / len(numbers)
        print('The average of numbers is', average)

main()
```

Finally, this line is a problem:

```
average = total / len(numbers)
```

`numbers` is the file object, not a list of numbers.  You need to read the numbers from the file into a list in order to do `len(numbers)`.

I think you actually want something like this:

```
def main():
    with open('numbers.txt') as numbers:
        list_numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers if x.strip()]
    average = sum(list_numbers) / len(list_numbers)
    print('The average of numbers is', average)  
main()
```

Using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), it will read-in all of the numbers from the file, convert them into integers, and then store them in a list.  Afterwards, we can easily find the average by diving the sum of the list by its length.

Comment: When i try to use your suggested code I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'.

Comment: Hmm, you must have a blank line in the file somewhere.  See my edit.  I added the `if x.strip()` filter to the list comprehension to skip blank lines.

Comment: You were right! Thanks for the help man, I really appreciate it.